# Prove the following using Chebyshev and Markov inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Show that
$$P(|X-\mu| \geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$

**Question: I know the exercise wants me to use Markov inequality and  Chebyshev inequality, but I can't reach the same answer. If someone can help me, it will be appreciated.**

Thanks!

Comment: You have stated the standard Chebyshev Inequality. Proofs can be found in many places, including the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Usually the Chebyshev inequality is either written that way or as $P(|X-\mu| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\varepsilon^2}$. Starting from the latter way of writing it, you can identify $k$ such that $\varepsilon=k \sigma$, and then the result follows.

Comment: "I know the exercise want me to use Markov inequality and chebyshev inequality, but I can't reach the same answer." Which answer can you reach?

Answer (score 1):

The Chebyshev inequality is 
$$\mathbb{P}(|x - \mu| \geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$$ .Substituting $$a = k\sigma $$gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks André, I found it.

For any event $A$, let $I_A$ be the indicator random variable of $A$, i.e. $I_A$ equals $1$ if $A$ occurs and $0$ otherwise. Then $\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$
\begin{align*}
\Pr(|X-\mu| \geq k\sigma) &=\E(I_{|X-\mu| \geq k\sigma}) \\
&= \E\left(I_{\left(\frac{X-\mu}{k\sigma}\right)^2 \geq 1}\right) \\
&\leq \E\left(\left(\frac{X-\mu}{k\sigma}\right)^2\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{k^2} \cdot \frac{\E((X-\mu)^2)}{k\sigma} \\
&=\frac{1}{k^2}.\end{align*}